# Typescript variable used before being assigned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm seeing an error in my Typescript / ReactJS project saying `Variable 'myVar' is used before being assigned.  TS2454`

I'm running TS version 4.2.3, and this error shows up in my IDE as well as when I try to run the code. However, it works fine in jsFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/d79L4ju8/) and I don't understand why the error would be thrown, since it seems like the variable is declared and checked:

```
interface testType {
    id: string,
    message: string,
}

let requestType = 'eventCreated';
let testVar = true;
let myVar: testType;

if (testVar) {
    myVar = {
        id: 'abc123',
        message: 'message goes here',
    }
}

switch (requestType) {
    case 'eventCreated':
        if (myVar !== undefined) { // error thrown here
            console.log(myVar);
        }
        break;
    case 'eventChanged':
        if (myVar !== undefined) {
            console.log(myVar);
        }
        break;
}
```

What's causing this to fail?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAkgZzAFQJ4AcUDeAUMqcsACYBcyGUoA5gDQlkC2EaacDENdjFgF8iRADYQwyKBACOAV05Y8KALzIA5BABuEcAGEZcSBQ0BucZNRKAanCjJ1YKIosSpbbHag15IChAwoBAUyAA+1hg4+GbIAPRxyAA8ALRp6RmZ6aLAMMgAFOhg3gCUyMRkyJ7ejuWslaSUNBpwAEYIAIwATADMGiwN7JzcvM0cXDwoDAD2nMgAFtAQ-fXIIiJEaADuwGAI8wUyCkrREGUVZAhwaChaugZGJhpUq5W5BdX2yACEqup+ASCIBC53iiWgUGmDjA80hWxACyWr0GyAQ0xAaGmEgAdGJpgx8p8oCULCi1sjSK0jABrUmXa63HR6MD6eZwEC8UwvMnvQleL6-f7+QLBCjnCkNNEYrEQXH4vmlOmDERkqkQOC0ohCIA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If testVar would not be assigned, the myVar would be used without being initialized. You could rewrite the code like so:

```
interface testType {
  id: string,
  message: string,
}

let requestType = 'eventCreated';
let testVar = true;
let myVar: testType | undefined = undefined;

if (testVar) {
  myVar = {
      id: 'abc123',
      message: 'message goes here',
  }
}

switch (requestType) {
  case 'eventCreated':
      if (myVar !== undefined) { // error thrown here
          console.log(myVar);
      }
      break;
  case 'eventChanged':
      if (myVar !== undefined) {
          console.log(myVar);
      }
      break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's throwing an error because the variable "myVar" is declared in a  condition; it possible that "myVar" will not be define in the condition so Typescript throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript considers all possible values for a variable, although sometimes it is overly defensive when guarding against uninitialised values. For example, you can see that there is no way for `A` not to be initialised here:

```
let A: string;

const B: boolean = true;

if (B) A = 'true';
if (!B) A = 'false';

const C = A.substring(1);
```

However, Typescript will complain (although in this example, it won't complain if you use a single if/else). If you are absolutely certain that your variable will be assigned in any eventuality, you can force the compiler to ignore, using the `!` operator:

```
const C = A!.substring(1);
```

The linter will complain about this though (`warning  Forbidden non-null assertion  @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion`).
You can disable this warning in your config file (eg. `.eslintrc.js`):

```
module.exports = {
  .....
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion': 'off'
  }
  .....
};
```